# Invalid CSRF token

Tags: spring-mvc, csrf-token

In certain flows in my web application I am getting csrf token invalid exception as follows:

> HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'ac6a93fd-6903-40f8-a5e2-00b9e830618b' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

Here CSRF token is present, it is not null, but invalid.Session did not expire.Faced similar issue as here [CSRF token not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57440160/http-status-403-expected-csrf-token-not-found-has-session-expired) and solved the same.
But here I am stuck.

**Edit:**

This issue crops up when we open multiple tabs in browser and from one of the tabs we logout and from another tab try to login from login page.

Answer (score 0):

Delete browser cookie and try again.

Generally token information is stored in cookie, in your case it seems old csrf token is still being used from cookie.